# Display alert Disabled when click outside in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-alertdialog

I have Implemented the Display alert for get confirmation from user. But it is disappeared when clicking outside of the alert box. Please suggest me how to handle the alert when clicking outside. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Show Sample Code xaml  and code behind / ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [this plugin](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup). In this plugin you can set CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked = false or true.

Comment: Yeah looks like he needs a modal pseudo alert, a custom dialog not an alert tbh.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable respose Miguel. But i don't need a plugin i need to be used alert. is there any other way like 'CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked = false' for dispalyalert in xamarin forms

Comment: With this plugin you can make Alerts